# Switch statement using or

Tags: c++, switch-statement, conditional-statements, or-operator

I'm creating a console app and using a `switch` statement to create a simple menu system. User input is in the form of a single character that displays on-screen as a capital letter. However, I do want the program to accept both lower- and upper-case characters.

I understand that `switch` statements are used to compare against constants, but is it possible to do something like the following?

```
switch(menuChoice) {
    case ('q' || 'Q'):
        //Some code
        break;
    case ('s' || 'S'):
        //More code
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If this isn't possible, is there a workaround? I really don't want to repeat code.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This way:

```
 switch(menuChoice) {
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        //Some code
        break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        //More code
        break;
    default:
 }
```

More on that topic:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Java.2C_PHP.2C_ActionScript.2C_JavaScript

Comment: This works because of the fall through mechanic ^^ which is also why the breaks after every isolated condition are necessary..

Just for those that might be new

Answer (score 27):

The generally accepted syntax for this is:

```
switch(menuChoice) {
    case 'q':
    case 'Q':
        //Some code
        break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        //More code
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

i.e.: Due the lack of a `break`, program execution cascades into the next block. This is often referred to as "fall through".

That said, you could of course simply normalise the case of the 'menuChoice' variable in this instance via toupper/tolower.

Comment: I think this should be the best answer not the one above - 
Not only it answer on how to resolve it but it also tells you why before you having to go a link that may or may not exist.

Answer (score 4):

`'q' || 'Q'` results in *bool* type result (*true*) which is promoted to integral type used in switch condition (*char*) - giving the value 1. If compiler allowed same value (1) to be used in multiple labels, during execution of *switch* statement `menuChoice` would be compared to value of 1 in each case. If `menuChoice` had value 1 then code under the first case label would have been executed.

Therefore suggested answers here use character constant (which is of type *char*) as integral value in each case label.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `tolower()`, here's my man:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>          #include ctype.h
>
> ```
>    int toupper(int c);
>    int tolower(int c);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>          toupper() converts the letter c to upper case, if possible.
>
> ```
>    tolower() converts the letter c to lower case, if possible.
>
>    If c is not an unsigned char value, or EOF, the behavior of these
>    functions is undefined.
> ```
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>          The value returned is that of the converted letter, or c if the
>   conversion was not possible.

So in your example you can `switch()` with:

```
switch(tolower(menuChoice)) {
    case('q'):
        // ...
        break;
    case('s'):
        // ...
        break;
}
```

Of course you can use both `toupper()` and `tolower()`, with capital and non-capital letters.

Answer (score 3):

You could (and for reasons of redability, should) before entering switch statement use tolower fnc on your var.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (toupper(choice))
{
  case 'Q':...
}
```

...or tolower.

Comment: you should (for portability reasons) use tolower, according to B.S.

Answer (score 2):

if you do

```
case('s' || 'S'):
    // some code
default:
    // some code
```

both `s` and `S` will be ignored and the default code will run whenever you input these characters. So you could decide to use

```
case 's':
case 'S':
    // some code
```

or

```
switch(toupper(choice){
    case 'S':
        // some code.
```

`toupper` will need you to include `ctype.h`.