# can we write this in C++ switch?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char i;
cin >>i;
switch (i){
 case ('e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'a'):
     cout<<"Vowel";
     break;
 case ('+'||'-'||'/'||'*'||'%'):
     cout<<"Op";
     break;
 }
return 0;  

}
```

if not than how can we use comparison or logical operators in switch ?
& why cant we declare and initialize variable in single case without using scope ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704986/switch-statement-using-or

Answer (score 7):

Without a break statement the previous cases "fall through" so this achieves the `||` you were looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   char i;
   cin >>i;
   switch (i){
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'a':
        cout<<"Vowel";
        break;
   case '+':
   case '-':
   case '/':
   case '*':
   case '%':
        cout<<"Op";
        break;
   }
   return 0;  
}
```

The answer to the other part of your question [is discussed in depth already on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92396/why-cant-variables-be-declared-in-a-switch-statement).

Comment: +1, for a correct answer to the first part and I would give another +1 for avoiding answer duplication by providing the link.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use fallthrough to map multiple case values to the same action.
2. The diagnostic message explains it -- it would be possible to jump over the initialization.  But isn't it just a warning?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't; in `switch`es you can only implicitly use the `==` operator and only on integral and enumeration types (§6.4.2). You should rewrite that `switch` as

```
switch (i){
 case 'e':
 case 'i':
 case 'o':
 case 'u':
 case 'a':
     cout<<"Vowel";
     break;
 case '+':
 case '-':
 case '/':
 case '*':
 case '%':
     cout<<"Op";
     break;
 }
```

which exploits the fall-through feature of the `switch` statement.

> if not than how can we use comparison or logical operators in switch ?

Simply, you can't. If you want to do anything different than equality comparison with integral/enumeration types you have to write several `if`/`else` statements.

> & why cant we declare and initialize variable in single case without using scope ?

It's not a problem of declaration, but of initialization; see the link in @awoodland's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Format it like this:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        cout << "Vowel";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, more terse solution:

```
#include <cstring>

// ...

if (strchr("eioua", i)) cout << "vowel";
if (strchr("+-/*%", i)) cout << "operator";
```

Note that `strchr` considers the terminating zero part of the string, so `i` should not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

We could, except it doesn't mean what is intended (and yields the same value in both cases): you'd be performing a **logical or** on a bunch of non-zero integer values and the result is **true** in both cases.