# Switch case with logical operator in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, or-operator

I am new to C and need help. My code is the following.

```
 #include<stdio.h>  
 #include<conio.h>  
 void main()
 {

  int suite=2;  

  switch(suite)
     {           
      case 1||2:
      printf("hi");

      case 3:
      printf("byee");

      default:
      printf("hello");
     }

  printf("I thought somebody");
  getche();
  }
```

I am working in Turbo C and the output is `helloI thought somebody`. There's no error message.

Please, let me know how this is working.

Comment: You should meet my friends: Enter and Space Bar.  They are really awesome and can make your code awesome too if you ask them nicely.

Comment: @BobKaufman I edited only partially - part of it was never saved. Thank DaoWen as well :-)

Comment: You would get much more helpful answers if you explained what you expected and why. I can think of several different ways this might not do what you expect, and it's entirely possible that you are expecting something else entirely. I'm not sure how we can explain why this doesn't do what you expect without knowing what you expect, other than by guessing right. (Are you expecting `case 1||2:` to act like `case 3:`? Or like `case 1: case 2:`? Or what?)

Comment: @Er -- outside of the formatting, this was a great first question.  A nice short extract, complete with the output you got from it and the mentioning of no errors.  I wish everyone posted questions this good.

Comment: also, please write `int main(void)` and stop using `void main()` and more importantly, stop using TurboC

Comment: @Aniket:- yeah actually I use gcc on linux but since my system is down , I have no choice.

Comment: okkay I will implement that thanks .

Comment: @ErAvinashSingh you have a choice, you can use GCC on windows with MinGW or Cygwin

Comment: You can also download Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop and hackaway!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch statement using or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704986/switch-statement-using-or)

Answer (score 15):

```
case 1||2:
```

Becomes `true`. so it becomes `case 1:` but the passed value is 2. so default case executed. After that your `printf("I thought somebody");` executed.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the OPs code did not act as he expected.

Comment: well yeah I thought it to be working like eithor 1 or 2 case .. but seems like it is working otherwise

Answer (score 9):

do this:

```
switch(suite){
  case 1:/*fall through*/
  case 2: 
    printf("Hi");
...
}
```

This will be a lot cleaner way to do that. The expression `1||2` evaluates to `1`, since `suite` was 2, it will neither match 1 nor 3, and jump to `default` case.

Comment: @JeffMercado thanks, I might look into how they work. Man 8 years with C and something of it still comes back and schools me

Comment: Aniket - Since there's no boolean type in C (they're just ints) the compiler will do constant-folding on `1||2`, like it would do on `0+1`, and you end up with `case 1` rather than the _1 or 2_ that the user might expect if they're coming from a language with full pattern matching with alternates.

Comment: ah yes @DaoWen I checked with my compiler. 1||2 evaluates to 1, which is true. And...

Answer (score 4):

```
case 1||2:
```

Results in

```
case 1:
```

because `1 || 2` evaluates to `1` (and remember; only constant integral expressions are allowed in `case` statements, so you cannot check for multiple values in one `case`).

You want to use:

```
case 1:
  // fallthrough
case 2:
```

Comment: `1||2` is a constant.  The compiler would have, at some point, reduced that value down.  Most likely at parse time.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: I didn't mean to say it wasn't (and I showed what it is reduced to in my first example), I figured that the OP wanted the same case for 1 and 2.  However, reading it again, I certainly worded that in a confusing way. I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: NP.  I know I like it when people tighten up my wording.

Answer (score 0):

You `switch` on value `2`, which matches `default` case in `switch` statement, so it prints "hello" and then the last line prints "I thought somebody".

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a switch statements in C compares your input argument to each case specified and enters the switch from that case. **It then keeps going until it hits a break statement, which isn't included in your code snippet.** I have a feeling that with the code below and an input of 2, you expected to see an output like "hiI thought somebody":

```
 switch(suite)
 {           
  case 1||2:
  printf("hi");

  case 3:
  printf("byee");

  default:
  printf("hello");
 }
```

Putting the logical operator question aside (lots of good answers for that above), even if this code entered the switch at case 1||2, your output would be "hibyeehelloI thought somebody". To fix, just add a break at the end of every case where you're expecting your code to do something:

```
 switch(suite)
 {           
  case 1:
  //fallthrough
  case 2:
  printf("hi");
  break;

  case 3:
  printf("byee");
  break;

  default:
  printf("hello");
  break;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
case (1||2):
  printf("hi");
```

Just put brackets and see the magic.

In your code,the program just check the first value and goes down.Since,it doesn't find 2 afterwards it goes to default case.

But when you specific that both terms i.e. 1 and 2 are together, using brackets, it runs as wished.