# How to write switch statement with "or" logic?

Tags: c, switch-statement, or-operator

Below, I have created a simple switch statement that works fine. I was wondering how I could change this code so it is switch(c), then case 1, case 2, case 3, default.

Example: `if char is 'w' || char is 'W' return WHITE`

I tried a simple if statement and it wasn't giving me the correct output despite it compiling successfully. Hope you can help. Thanks! :)

```
static COLORS color(char c) {

    switch(toupper(c)) {

        case 'W' : return WHITE;

        case 'B' : return BLUE;

        case 'R' : return RED;

        default  : return DEFAULT;
    }
}
```

Comment: case 'w' : return WHITE; case 'W' : return WHITE;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch statement using or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704986/switch-statement-using-or)

Answer (score 15):

You can simply bunch together multiple cases:

```
switch (c) {
  case 'w':
  case 'W':
    // Code
    break;
  default:
    // Code
}
```

See MSDN [switch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following

```
switch (c) { 
  case 'w':
  case 'W':
    return WHITE;
  case 'b':
  case 'B':
    return BLUE;
  case 'r':
  case 'R':
    return RED;
  default:
    return DEFAULT;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(c){

    case 'w' :
    case 'W' : return WHITE;

    case 'b' :
    case 'B' : return BLUE;

    case 'r' :
    case 'R' : return RED;

    default  : return DEFAULT;
}
```

Will work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you could try `switch((islower(c) ? toupper(c): c))` and retain the rest of the code in the current form.

Comment: I would just write `toupper(c)`, but +1 for this different approach.