# Defining a match-case statement with the same instruction for two different cases in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I would like to create a match-case statement in Python in which two cases do the same instruction. For instance, if Python behaved like C++, according to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4704986/4382986), I would write the match-case statement as:

```
        match x:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                # Some code
                break
            case 3:
                # Some code
                break
```

The code however does not work, showing that the match-case statement needs to be written in a different way in Python. What is this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
match x:
    case 1 | 2:
        # Some code
    case 3:
        # Some code
```

Python match clauses don't fall through, so you can't concatenate them as in C and you don't use `break` at the end of the clause.

The ["OR pattern"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/#or-patterns) (as shown, where `|` means "or") can be used with subpatterns which bind variables, but all the subpatterns need to bind the same variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just my own 2 cents, according to the [official Python 3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/controlflow.html), in a match-case you can combine several literals in a single pattern using | (“or”). In your case, it would look like this:

```
def x(num):
    match num:
        case 1 | 2:
            # your codes...
        case 3:
            # your codes...
        case _:
            # This is the wildcard pattern and it never fails to match.


# call your function
x(6)    # This will result in the wildcard pattern since case 6 isn't specified.
```

Hope this helps someone else out there!